# How to access private member from lambda that is passed to constructor of friendly class?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, compiler-errors

How can I access static member from lambda here?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::function<void()> f)
    {
        f();
    }
};

class B
{
private:
    friend class A;
    static bool c;
};

bool B::c = false;

A a([]() { B::c = true; });
```

This code gives me error C2248:

> 'B::c': cannot access private member declared in class 'B'

Comment: I don't think this will ever work. I think that a (static) member function of A would have be the one to change it.

Comment: You can't declare the lambda as a friend. If you want behavior like this, there are some tricks you can do to expose `c`, but it depends on how much you are willing to change / whether the lambda is internal code or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access static member from lambda here.

You mark class `A` as a friend, but the lambda you create is not related to `A` or `B` directly - it has it's own type which, of course, is not a friend of `B`. That's why you have an error trying to access `B::c`.

You might consider passing `B::c` to `f` from `A` constructor as an alternative:

```
class A;

class B
{
private:
    friend class A;
    static bool c;
};

bool B::c = false;

class A
{
public:
    A(std::function<void(bool&)> f)
    {
        f(B::c);
    }
};

A a([](bool& value) { value = true; });
```